# Select last salary

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

## I have Two Table ( My example):

## TB1

```
Emp_code     salary     year   month 
-------      -----      ----   -----
1             2000       2015   1
1             2000       2015   2 
2             4000       2015   2
2             4000       2015   3
```

## TB2

```
code          name       Age 
-------      -----      ----   
1             MMMM       32
1             MMMM       32 
2             KKKK       25   
2             KKKK       25
```

I need select the last (month and year) get salary >>

the Result  should be show like the following table>>

```
code          name       Age    salary   year   month
-------      -----      ----    ------   ----   -----
1             MMMM       32      2000    2015     2
2             KKKK       25      4000    2015     3
```

Comment: Why does your data have so many duplicates?  It seems like a bad data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### create script for employee and salary table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
[Empcode] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Age] [varchar](50) NULL) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Salary](
[Empcode] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Salary] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Year] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Month] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

### salary table data

```
1   10000   2017    1
1   10000   2017    2
2   40000   2017    2
2   40000   2017    3
```

### employee table data

```
1   aaa 25
2   bbb 25
```

### Query :-

```
select e.empcode,e.name,e.age,s.salary,max(s.year) as year,max(s.month) as month from salary s join employee e on s.empcode=e.empcode group by e.empcode,e.name,e.age,s.salary
```

### output :-

```
1   aaa 25  10000   2017    2
2   bbb 25  40000   2017    3
```

Comment: 1   10000   2017    1
1   10000   2016   12

Comment: this solution in same year but if different year

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM ( 
       SELECT t1.code,
              t2.name,
              t2.Age,
              t1.salary,
              t1.year,
              t1.month,
              ROW_NUMBER OVER(PARTITION BY t1.Emp_code ORDER BY t1.year desc,t1.month desc) AS RN 
       FROM TB1 t1
       INNER JOIN TB2 t2 ON t1.Emp_code=t2.code
                                                 ) X
WHERE X.RN=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions and `distinct`:

```
select . . .
from (select tb1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by emp_code order by year desc, month desc) as seqnum
      from tb1
     ) tb1 join
     (select distinct tb2.*
      from tb2
     ) tb2
     on tb1.code = tb2.emp_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try below statements to get your desired result ;      

CREATE TABLE #Table(Emp_code INT,salary INT,_year INT,  _month INT)
CREATE TABLE #Table1(code INT,name VARCHAR(100), Age INT)

INSERT INTO  #Table(Emp_code ,salary , _year ,   _month)
SELECT 1,2000,2015,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,2000,2015,2 UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,4000,2015,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,4000,2015,3

INSERT INTO  #Table1(code ,name , Age)
SELECT 1,'MMMM',32 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'MMMM',32 UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,'KKKK',25 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'KKKK',25 

SELECT DISTINCT code ,name , Age , salary , _year , A._month
FROM #Table1
JOIN
(
  SELECT Emp_code ,MAX(_month) _month
  FROM #Table
  GROUP BY Emp_code 
) A ON Emp_code = code  
JOIN #Table T ON A.Emp_code = T.Emp_code AND A._month = T._month
```